# How to get all server member IDs? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am new to Discord.js which means I mostly copy the code and I've got a problem. I cant seem to find a way to get all my server member IDs in the serverUsers array. I know there are already a lot of questions that have answers, but the solutions don't seem to work for me, this one put in only the bot's, that is running the script, user ID.

```
client.on("ready", readyDiscord);

function readyDiscord() {
    console.log("Authentication complete");
    console.log("Going online");

    var serverUsers = []

    const MyServer = client.guilds.cache.get("MyServerID");
    MyServer.members.cache.forEach(member => serverUsers.push(member.user.id));

    console.log(serverUsers);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this without going through such trouble

```js
const serverUsers = client.guilds.cache.get("Server ID").members.cache.map(member => member.id);
console.log(serverUsers);
```

Docs:
[members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, but my bot gives out only its id, does it give out only id's from players in the same role or something like that. If its not that, then what could it be?